# How to get the Node name in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cql

I am new to Neo4j and am referring to [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/neo4j/neo4j_cql_creating_relationship.htm).

I am not finding any answer on how to fetch the node name using CQL.
For example:

If I create two nodes like so:

```
CREATE (Dhawan:player{name: "Shikar Dhawan", YOB: 1985, POB: "Delhi"}) 
CREATE (Ind:Country {name: "India"})
```

and then build relationship at a later date using:

```
CREATE (Dhawan)-[r:BATSMAN_OF]->(Ind)
```

How do we know the node name: Dhawan or Ind?
Using:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n
```

I am getting back the label name but not the node name!
How do I get all the details of an existing graph DB?

Comment: did you try `MATCH (n) RETURN n.name`? Because if you want a property to be displayed you've to get it using `.`. Hope you find it useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you're calling "the node name" is actually a variable, and is only present for the duration of a single query (or less, if you don't include it in a WITH clause and it goes out of scope). It is never saved to the graph db, and is not persisted data.

In your example, you would only be able to use `CREATE (Dhawan)-[r:BATSMAN_OF]->(Ind)` (and have those variables refer to your previously created nodes) if the create was performed in the same query where those variables were previously bound (and still in scope).

Otherwise, this would create two new nodes, create the :BATSMAN_OF relationship between them, and bind those variables to the new nodes for the duration of their scope.

Comment: Thank you InverseFalcon. It now makes sense. Could you please recommend any book/URL for this much in depth explanation.

Comment: You may want to go through the developers manual completely from the beginning. The [section on variables](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/variables/) is short, but in conjunction with the rest of the manual it should be clear that these are short-lived and not persisted.